# how do I perform the before calculation in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, shift

Hi Assuming I have a df

```
x=[.12,.02,.05,.04]
y=[1,1,1,1]
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x,y=y))
```

[image]

but I want to change values under column 'y' in way that first row is 100, 2nd row is 102 (i.e. 100*.02) third row is 107.1 (102*1.05) and so on.

How do I do that? (I think it should be done using shift function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `cumprod()`. It requiered a bit of a hardcoding for the first number, afterwards it seems fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x=[.12,.02,.05,.04]
y=[1,1,1,1]
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x,y=y))

df['x'] = df['x'] + 1 #Add 1 to make the cumprod() easier
df['y'].loc[0] = 100 #Force the first value to be 100
df['y'].loc[1:] = df['x'].loc[1:].cumprod() * df['y']
df['x'] = df['x'] - 1 #Substract 1 to keep original values
```

Output:

```
      x          y
0  0.12  100.00000
1  0.02    1.02000
2  0.05    1.07100
3  0.04    1.11384
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess below is what you need

```
df.loc[0,'y'] = 100
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'y'] = df.loc[i-1, 'y'] * (df.loc[i, 'x'] + df.loc[i, 'y'])

    x       y
0   0.12    100.000
1   0.02    102.000
2   0.05    107.100
3   0.04    111.384
```

Comment: yeh that works! thanks v m. can't be done without a for loop?

Comment: please see my edit, my actual df is huge - so want to see if for loop can be avoided

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do this operation: `y = 100*(x+y)`.

If that's the case, you can do the following:

```
df['y'] = 100*df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: No, OP is asking for a cummulative product.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
df.loc[i, 'y'] = 100 
for i in range(1, len(df)): 
    df.loc[i, 'y'] = df.loc[i - 1, 'y'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'x'])
```

output:

```
      x        y
0  0.12  100.000
1  0.02  102.000
2  0.05  107.100
3  0.04  111.384
```